# Getting value from array and count difference between dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with counting days between end_at and start_at located in object @nearest_vacation.
Structure of object @nearest_vacation:

```
[#<Vacation id: 11, start_at: "2016-04-30", end_at: "2016-05-02", free: false, reason: "Rocznica", person_id: 1>]
```

When I try `@nearest_vacation.map{|x| x.end_at}` it returns: `[Mon, 02 May 2016]`
This format of date doesn't allow me to do like that: `(end_at - start_at).to_i`. How to properly get values end_at and start_at to calculate difference between dates?

Comment: Why do you have an array? Surely you only want a single instance of vacation. How did you retrieve this record?

Comment: `This format of date doesn't allow me to do like that: (end_at - start_at).to_i` Did you try this? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Alfie the 'format' of that date is fine, its the fact that its in an array thats the problem.

Comment: So shouldn't this work : `@nearest_vacation.map{|x| (x.end_at x.start_at).to_i}`

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: @DickieBoy problem was.first(1) instead .first (first value of nearest_vacations)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, `first` with no args will return a single instance whereas first(an_integer) will return an array on the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an array of `Vacations`.

If you truly need an array, no problem.

```
# notice the pluralised variable name
@nearest_vacations.map{|nv| (nv.end_at - nv.start_at)}
```

The above will return you an array with the differences in dates.

What I suspect is going on here is that you have arrays and instances confused. Which is why you have had to use `.map` to get the `end_at` value from your array of vacations.

I *think* the real question here is why your `nearest_vacation` is an array. The name of the variable and the fact its not pluralised tells me that you don't want an array, but just one instance. Find where your `nearest_vacation` variable is being set to an array, fix that, then your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mjd`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/mjd) method:

```
Date.parse("2016-05-02").mjd - Date.parse("2016-04-20").mjd
=> 12 #days
```